# Increasing power output of microwave oven

Tags: electrical-engineering

Microwave oven uses magnetron to generate hugh power em waves. How the power output of a microwave can be increased? It uses a 1-2 KVAC capacitor. Will doubling the voltage of capacitor double the power output?

Comment: Why would you think doubling the capacitor voltage will double the power?

Comment: The capacitor voltage is just the max voltage it can accept without blowing up. It won't magically produce more voltage. The actual work would involve replacing pretty much everything on the high-voltage side, meaning you're practically replacing your microwave, only keeping the old chassis and little meaningless dings like the plate motor or pushbuttons.

Comment: Just buy a new one ; the power seems to be increased every year. The original home microwaves were about 500 watts. I think they are over 1200 watts today.

Comment: It may be possible to overdrive the magnetron (and every other component) by adding some windings to the transformer secondary, thereby increasing the voltage slightly. Note however that the magnetron is highly non-linear so this is not "safe" in any way. See here: https://www.thermex-thermatron.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Magentrons101_v3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not. the power output of a microwave oven is set by the power rating of the magnetron tube that generates the microwaves. If you want more microwave power, you need a more powerful magnetron tube, and a larger power supply to drive it as well.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change the magnetron and change the capacitor for a higher capacitance. Most lower wattage microwaves have lower capacitance capacitors. Or you can ditch the Microwave oven transformer and capacitor idea together. You can replace it with a panasonic DC to AC high voltage Power Converter. Those are more efficient and are usually higher wattage. Most of the time 1200 watts. But be careful when changing stuff in a microwave, because it can kill you! Always disconnect the cord and discharge the High Voltage Capacitor if your microwave has one! Consider to either by a new one or ask a trained electrician to to it.